# Download files from UIDocumentPicker and wait until download has finished

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, download, uidocumentpickervc

I'm trying to download a file from the

```
-documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:
```

method.
I've tried to get the data of the file using

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

but it didn't work how I expected, because the UIDocumentPicker fires the -documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL: -method before the file is downloaded.

How can I get the NSData from the file when it's downloaded?

Thanks in advance, Fabian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file actually is downloaded, but you need to use a file coordinator to read the file contents.  Something like this should do:

```
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSFileCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [coordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:0 error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL];
        // Do something
    }];
    if (error) {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to use NSFileCoordinator because this delegate call seems to be synchronous and dataWithContents works perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, it wasn't working for him.  Plus, I think avoiding NSFileCoordinator leaves too much to chance.  Apple says, "All file-related operations must be performed through a file coordinator object." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html

Comment: That's right. But with the iOS update to iOS 8.3 the UIDocumentPicker downloads the file showing an activity indicator before dismissing. When the UIDocumentPicker is actually dismissed, I can access the file without the NSFileCoordinator.

Comment: Unless it changes while you're accessing it, of course.  An iCloud sync can happen at any time.  BTW, I did notice the activity indicator, and was very happy to see it.

Comment: Can you help with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30613645/add-edit-in-exel-or-edit-photo-extension